# inserting binding.pry changes which rspec tests pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, scope, pry, database-cleaner

tl;dr:  I was trying to test that the correct items were added to an array.  When I ran the test, it said that things were being added to the array indiscriminately.  However, when I put a binding.pry in the first line of LessonPackage.available, the tests pass... but now, two other tests fail.

Now here's some code.

In the original test, I test that the correct number of items are added to an array.  This tests the :current scope.  Here's the test:

```
describe 'manage multiple lessons' do
  before :all do
    @six_package = create(:lesson_package)
    @thirteen_package = create(:lesson_package, name: 'thirteen', number_of_lessons: 13)
    @old_package = create(:lesson_package, name: 'canceled', current: false)
    @instructor = create(:instructor, base_lesson_price: 50, contract_rate: 40)
  end

  context 'available' do
    it 'return array of all available package managers when given defaults' do
      packages = LessonPackage.available(@instructor)
      packages.length.should be 2
      packages[0].class.should be LessonPackageManager
    end
  end
end
```

Notice that @old_package should have a 'current' attribute of false.  Here's the code under test:

```
class LessonPackage < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :current, where(current: true)
  ...
  def self.available(instructor, method = 'self', lesson_type = 'private')
    LessonPackage.current.map do |package|
      manager = LessonPackageManager.make_package(instructor, package, lesson_type)
      manager.send(method)
    end
  end
end
```

The test fails!  But I know this code works, not only because it works in development mode, but because when I put binding.pry in the first line of LessonPackage.available, it suddenly works!  But now another test is broken:

```
describe 'managed lesson' do
  before :all do
    @six_package = create(:lesson_package)
    @instructor = create(:instructor, base_lesson_price: 50, contract_rate: 35)
  end

    describe 'booking lessons with a student' do
      before :each do
        @student = create(:student, area: 'herethere')
        package_manager = LessonPackage.manage('six', @instructor)
        package_manager.add_to_cart(@student)
      end

      subject {LessonBooking.first}

      its(:lesson_package)    {should eq @six_package}
    end
  end
end
```

The reason given is that the lesson package attached to the first lesson booking has a different id than the original lesson package created.  Note:  THIS TEST WAS WORKING BEFORE.  The ONLY thing different is the binding.pry.

I'm using database_cleaner, and this is how I have it configured:

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```